# How to find contiguous regions in 2D Data

Tags: scikit-learn

I'd like to label non-contiguous regions in an image with different labels.
I guess this should be possible with scikit-learn.
The image is stored for example in a 2D numpy.ndarray with zeroes and ones, the ones beeing different contiguous regions.

Let's have a look at the following very simple array where we have two contiguous regions of ones but these to regions are separated from each other by zeroes.

```
np.array([
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]
], dtype = int)
```

the algorithm should label the top-left contiguous region with a label like '1' and the right bottom contiguous region with a second label '2'.

```
np.array([
        [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2],
        [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2],
        [1, 1, 0, 2, 2, 2]
], dtype = int)
```

**Any hints how to do this?**

Comment: This is called binary image segmentation and you can do it in [`scikit-image`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/tutorial_segmentation.html). If your image is already good (and it looks like it is) then you can probably just use [`scipy.ndimage.label()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html).

Comment: thanks, scipy.ndimage.label() works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label

a = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
              [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
              [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1],
              [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]], dtype = int)

label(a)
```

Comment: thanks again. skimage.measure.label() works nicely too.